# Use user info in PHP after logging in with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently writing a facebook app. In my app, the user is identified with the Javascript FB SDK:

```
    FB.init({
            appId  : appId,
            status : true, 
            cookie : true, 
            xfbml  : true, 
        });

  FB.ui({method: 'oauth'  
        ,client_id: appId  
        ,redirect_uri: 'some_URI'  
        ,scope: 'publish_stream'});`
```

After the user loggs in, I can get the access token like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
    alert(response.session.access_token);
```

My question is, if I could pass it back to the php code in order to use it?

Answer (score 0):

you can send it via ajax request to your php script & use/operate with it as you want

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Well, theoretically you could just do a ajax query and send the access token back to a php, e.g.
http://www.mydomain.com/setfbtoken?token=

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the session should be attached to your url as a get parameter (at least it is in PHP), so you could just fetch it off the $_GET parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't think that the $_GET['session'} is the same as the response.session.

Comment: Well I have never used the javascript implementation so I can't tell for sure. It should still work using something like: 
    var myRequest = new Request.HTML ({ 
        url: 'data.php', 
        data: {acccesstoken: response.session.access_token}
    }).send();

IF you are using mootools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this as in theory you should have the facebook cookie.

The information I posted here [Facebook PHP SDK getSession() fails to get session. Cookie problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272099/facebook-php-sdk-getsession-fails-to-get-session-cookie-problem/6517253#6517253) might be useful and the functions listed there.