# Facebook - JavaScript SDK - How to ask for permission automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using HTML 5 to develop a few things and inserting Facebook JavaScript SDK within the same.

I have developed a Facebook application where I want to:

1) If user is not logged in facebook, it will ask for login, but if the user is logged in and opens the application, it should ask for the persmission automatically rather than the user needing to click the link having `FB.LOGIN()` again.

There is one Stack Overflow question, *[How do I get my Facebook application to automatically ask for the required permissions post installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955615)* where they do it by using `window.top.location = "<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>";`, but how can I find this authenication URL within JavaScript?

JavaScript code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'appid', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//www.domain.com/channel.html', // Channel file
            status     : true, // Check login status
            cookie     : true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // Parse XFBML
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedinnotauthenticate').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('loginauthenicated').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else
                if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=id&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/appp/";
                }
                else {
                    window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=id&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=http://apps.facebook.com/appp/";
                }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
    else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
                token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            }
            else {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {scope: 'user_location'});
    }
},true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option for you is to use the [authenticated referrals](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) feature which means that Facebook will take care of the authentication for you, along with the permissions you need.

The user will be passed to your application only after the user went through the authentication process.

If that does not suit you for any reason, please check out the documentation for [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and especially the [server-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) since it seems like that's what you're after from what you've wrote.

From your JavaScript code, it seems that you are not using the channel URL property when you init the Facebook SDK. As it states in the [JavaScript SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (*Channel File* section):

> The channel file addresses some issues with cross domain communication
>   in certain browsers

And then:

> The channelUrl parameter is optional, but recommended.

I can't promise that it will fix it, but it might.

It should be like this:

```
// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'appid', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//www.domain.com/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // Check login status
        cookie     : true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the  session
        xfbml      : true  // Parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedinnotauthenticate').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('loginauthenicated').style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
            if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=id&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/appp/";
            }
            else {
                window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=id&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=http://apps.facebook.com/appp/";
            }
});

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

As you can see, first you need to define the *window.fbAsyncInit* callback method, and only then load the SDK.

Comment: Hi Nitzan,

Thanks for the details. https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/testnamespace This is working but i tried using 3 accounts. in some account, when user is redirected to this string, it shows "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Can u please give any idea?

Comment: The redirect_uri should not be a facebook domain url like you wrote, you should redirect to your own server, then you need to process what it is you want, and then redirect the user to *http://apps.facebook....*

Comment: But they have mentioned that we can do like this in, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/. Also this was working before some time. Is it related to slow network where js is not loaded properly

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it does say that there, my bad. At what point exactly does that account get that error?

Comment: sometime only.. right now its working fine. but seems issue seems related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884878/facebook-occasionally-shows-an-error-occurred-please-try-again-later-when-my

Also, if user is not logged in and they open the app page.. i give link with fb.login() which ask for user persmission. but once user give permission. it does reload the page so my main screen not come till i refresh it

Comment: At what stage does the error occur when it does? Do you see that error message instead of your canvas page when the user is being redirected back?

Comment: Well, try to redirect to your server instead for the apps.facebook.com. Then take the code they give you and exchange it with an access token from your server, then if everything worked fine redirect the user back to the canvas page at apps.facebook.com. I'm not sure why you get this error, but my guess is that the flow I just described won't end up with that error.

Comment: i tried but still soemtime the issue coems. I think this is related to loading of js as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884878/facebook-occasionally-shows-an-error-occurred-please-try-again-later-when-my

do u have any idea to check where loading of sdk is finished before i fire any api request in new oauth?

Comment: Oh, see that's why I asked at what stage the error occurs..  If it's a js thing, can you please edit your question and add the js code you are using?

Comment: No, that's no good, as I wrote you: *EDIT YOU QUESTION*, pasting the code in a few comments is just not readable. Please fix that and delete all of the code comments. As for your problem, I'm modifying my original answer with what I think is wrong.

Comment: Um, you should first define the *window.fbAsyncInit* callback and **only then** load the SDK. Try that, hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: means.. can u please send overalall idea for that? thanks for such help till now

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i ll check this

Comment: No probs. If it turns out to fix the problem, don't forget to accept the answer.