# Displaying authorization dialog in case user is signed in Facebook

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

When I use the following link from my app in case the user is not logged in Facebook the Facebook login shows and then user authenticate the app and then the app shows.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=521577774587246&redirect_uri=http://localhost:55549/fb/&scope=email,read_stream">Facebook</a>
```

If user is logged in and search for the app from the Facebook search box then it shows the default.aspx with a Facebook login button.

How can I show the user the authorization dialog instead of the Login button ?

Following is the default.aspx javascript -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '521577774587246', // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    // TODO: Handle the access token

                    // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                    // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                    form.setAttribute("action", 'loadMainPage.ashx');

                    var field = document.createElement("input");
                    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                    field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                    form.appendChild(field);
                    //                    alert(accessToken);
                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app

                    window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=521599834587246&redirect_uri=http://localhost:55549/fb/&scope=email,read_stream";
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.

                }
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040804/facebook-javascript-sdk-how-to-ask-for-permission-automatically)  I used FB.login instead the *FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange'* and now it asks for authorization.